# mysqli insert in php

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

Hi i am new to Msqli because i am now migrating all my mysql codes. because mysql is now deprecated i have now my connection

```
    function rlConnection()
{
    global $g_link;
    if( $g_link )
        return $g_link;
    $g_link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password') or die('Could not connect to server.' );
    mysql_select_db('forum', $g_link) or die('Could not select database.');
    return $g_link;
}

function CleanConnection()
{
    global $g_link;
    if( $g_link != false )
        mysql_close($g_link);
    $g_link = false;
}
```

and i am tring to insert some value and giving me this error

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in**

The code for above error is

```
        include("dbconfig.php");

    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");       

    $pid = $_POST['categories'];
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['forumname']);
    $description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);

    $date = time();
    $locked = 0;

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO forum (pid, name, description) VALUES ('$pid', '$name', '$description')", rlConnection()  );
```

i need some quick advice thanks in advance and btw sorry for my poor English..

Comment: Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix your injection problems. Use statements and bind variables.

Comment: ok so you suggest that it was right for me to stay in Mysql? well yes i can bind variables but i am not sure about it lol.. 

I have this simple forum that i made for my website that is pure mysql. i am just trying to migrate but kinda gives me a little confusions because i am not really a skilled or titled programmer i just learned it all from searching since from yahoo search before google haha here it is.. www . wydpilipinas . com/forum

Comment: No way. You **should** use `mysqli` with statements/bound variables or `PDO`. It's not amazingly difficult to turn into `mysqli` with bound parameters if you make a simple prepare wrapper function.

Comment: Ok h2oooooooooo maybe i decided to finish my own project first then i really need to learned this MySQLI... because first i learned mysql it was 6Months for me to understand how it works hehehe btw thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [mysqli_query](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) documentation. The first parameter is expected to be a mysqli link.

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Essentially, what `$g_link` is:

```
mysqli_query(rlConnection(), "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
mysqli_query(rlConnection(), "INSERT INTO forum (pid, name, description) VALUES ('$pid', '$name', '$description')");
```

Then change your connection string to use `mysqli_connect`

```
$g_link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'forum')
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.. this wont resolve my problem... better stay in Deprecated mysql for now..